# model-file is too big

Tags: modeling

I´m realatively new to Blender. I am currently modelling a bigger model and working on the highpoly version of it. My problem is, that the blender-file is getting really big (~2GB). And I also dont want to loose detail, like cracks and so on.
Is there a way to shrink the file without loosing any deatil?

Comment: Are you running short on disk space? Shrinking file size on its own will gain you nothing other than saving storage space. You can artificially make a file smaller by compressing it, but that wont necessarily guarantee better performance, nor faster renders. What exact issues are you experiencing? What does your file contain? How did you model it? Without details it will be hard to help

Comment: Turn on blend file compression in the preferences, save and load> compress file